# I forgot where I'm supposed to go, is there a way to find out?

Tags: cross-country-canada

[Having made my first couple of journeys](https://archive.org/details/msdos_Crosscountry_Canada_1991), this is the state of play:

[image]

My problem is due to the overwhelming intensity of the graphics and immersive gameplay, I've forgotten what my original mission was. I needed to go to a city to pick up some 'commodities'. Is there a way to find out which one it is?

Comment: Oh god, I used to know this game inside out and sideways. I hung out in the computer lab playing it instead of going to school dances in middle school. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type "inventory" - this should tell you the date, what you've already picked up, and what you need to pick up next, if anything, along with where you need to go to finish the game (your final destination).